# Wordpress BO post.php - button Publish/Update not working (error : GET 400 bad request, rest_invalid_param, orderby=menu_order)

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by, bad-request

I'm facing a weird issue on Wordpress…
I have to do some minor content updates on a Wordpress online since 2020, running perfectly.
But for only one of the CPT, when I want to add/modify a post, the publish/update (and save as draft) buttons not working. I can click on them but nothing happens…

In my console, I spot the following errors :

> 400 Bad Request GET https://*mywebsite*/wp-json/wp/v2/challenges?per_page=100&exclude=1921&parent_exclude=1921&orderby=menu_order&order=asc&_fields=id%2Ctitle%2Cparent&context=edit&_locale=user

> Uncaught (in promise)
> Object { code: "rest_invalid_param", message: "Paramètre(s) non valide(s) : orderby", data: {…} } in data.min.js:2:32702

I can update content without any problem with the quick edit…

Has anyone ever encountered this error?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix here :
[Tim Ross webdevelopment](https://www.timrosswebdevelopment.com/wordpress-rest-api-post-order/)

I had to add to functions.php the following code :

```
// This enables the orderby=menu_order for Posts
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );
// And this for a custom post type called 'portfolio'
add_filter( 'rest_challenges_collection_params', 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );
//Add menu_order to the list of permitted orderby values function filter_add_rest_orderby_params( $params ) {
$params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';
return $params;
}
```

The filter hook is called rest_{post_type}_collection_params.
In my case, the post_type is "challenges".